# Reference Request: Infinite-Dimensional Analysis

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, hilbert-spaces, differential-topology

I am aware that there is a whole lot of literature out there on the expansive field of *infinite-dimensional analysis*. Moreover, almost every book I've glanced at so far seems to have a different focus than the next one. Specifically, I am interested in the study of maps $f: M \to H$, where $M$ is a *finite-dimensional* manifold and $H$ is a Hilbert space (or a Banach space). Here are some concrete topics that I want to learn more about

a) Fréchet-Derivatives (generalizing total derivatives), Gateaux-Derivaties (generalizing directional derivates), their connection, and the infinite-dimensional analogue of classic theorems such as the *Mean-Value Theorem* or *Schwarz' theorem*.

b) **(This is most important to me)** Differential forms over $M$ with values in $H$, the corresponding concept of *exterior derivative* on such forms, integrating $k$-forms over $k$-dimensional embedded submanifolds (via the *Bochner Integral*) and a generalization of *Stokes Theorem*.

Does anybody know a good reference for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out  Cartan's "Differential Forms" in that book the very first definition of differential forms deals with forms defined over an open  subset of a Banach and with values in a Banach.